# Escape quote in sql statement Object C

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm having an issue with a single quote in sql.  Below is the statement.

If the Users name is Mom's how do I select it?  I also want to take account for sometimes I might have to escape a `'` and sometimes not

```
sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM USERS where NAME = '%@'",searchKeyword];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB instead](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Answer (score 2):

You should not construct the SQL query manually like that. It opens the door to SQL injection of all kinds, allowing a nefarious user to run arbitrary SQL on your database.

Instead you should use bound parameters. See http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

(I assume you're intending to do a SQLite query).